# Assigning a group while adding user in django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

In my application, I have models that have the Users model as a Foreign key, eg:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):    
username=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
...
```

In the admin site, when adding a new Doctor, I have the option of adding a new User next to the username field. This is exactly what I want, but in the dialog that opens, it asks for a username and password for the new user; I would also like to be able to assign a group to this new user. What would be the best way of doing this ?

Thanks,
lokharkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application, create an 'admin.py', where you actually register your own model to admin, add following code.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A form that overrides the UserCreationForm
    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "groups")

UserAdmin.add_form = MyUserCreationForm

admin.site.register(Doctor)
```

Now you just need to override the template that render this overridden form.
Create a directory structure as,

```
"your_project_root_directory"/templates/admin/auth/user/add_form.html
```

and copy the content as,

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block after_field_sets %}

<p>{% trans "First, enter a username and password. Then, you'll be able to edit more user options." %}</p>

<fieldset class="module aligned">

<div class="form-row">
  {{ form.username.errors }}
  {# TODO: get required class on label_tag #}
  <label for="id_username" class="required">{% trans 'Username' %}:</label> {{ form.username }}
  <p class="help">{{ form.username.help_text }}</p>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  {{ form.password1.errors }}
  {# TODO: get required class on label_tag #}
  <label for="id_password1" class="required">{% trans 'Password' %}:</label> {{ form.password1 }}
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  {{ form.password2.errors }}
  {# TODO: get required class on label_tag #}
  <label for="id_password2" class="required">{% trans 'Password (again)' %}:</label> {{ form.password2 }}
  <p class="help">{% trans 'Enter the same password as above, for verification.' %}</p>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  {{ form.groups.errors }}
  {# TODO: get required class on label_tag #}
  <label for="id_groups" class="required">{% trans 'Groups' %}:</label> {{ form.groups }}
  <p class="help">{% trans 'All existing Groups listed here. If you are not seeing any group, means you dont have any groups object created.' %}</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("id_username").focus();</script>

</fieldset>
{% endblock %}
```

And you are good to go. Its working snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, is this type of solution considered kosher in Django?  That is, it seems like copy/pasting a big chunk of code like this goes against the DRY principle that the Django developers promote.

Comment: DRY is very good practice whenever possible -- sometimes fine tuning requires going against such practice