# Assign User-objects to a Group while editing Group-object in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, membership, usergroups

In the default Django admin view for user-object (edit user) one can edit the user's group memberships. What if I wanted this the other way around also? I.e. in the group editing page one could select the users that belong to the group being edited.

As I see this, Django doesn't have a ManyToMany mapping from Group to User object which makes it impossible(?) to implement a ModelAdmin class for this particular case. If I could make an additional UsersOfGroup model class and use it in the Django's Group model's ManyToMany field as a through-attribute, there could be a way.

Any ideas, is this possible to implement using ModelAdmin tricks or do I just have to make a custom view for editing groups?

I have checked these two other questions, but they don't quite do the same thing:

[Assigning a group while adding user in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864261/assigning-a-group-while-adding-user-in-django-admin)

and

[Show group membership in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180628/django-users-and-groups-show-group-membership-in-admin)

**Updated:**
The answer from Chris was almost there. :) The group has a reference to the users set, but it's called *user_set*, not *users*. So these are the changes I made:

```
if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
    self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.user_set.all()
```

and

```
if group.pk:
    group.user_set = self.cleaned_data['users']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**yourapp/admin.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), 
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name=_('Users'),
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Group

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.users.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        group = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            group.save()

        if group.pk:
            group.users = self.cleaned_data['users']
            self.save_m2m()

        return group

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupAdminForm

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I had to edit it a bit, but basically this was the solution.

Comment: The above code worked for me. Only change i had to do was change self.instance.users.all() to self.instance.user_set.all()

Comment: this code does not work, in that when you add users to the group, and save, your changes are note saved. The solution by `tomka` below does work with recente Django and Python

Answer (score 4):

The save method above won't work if you add a new group and simultaneously add users to the group. The problem is that the new group won't get saved (the admin uses commit=False) and won't have a primary key. Since the purpose of save_m2m() is to allow the calling view to handle saving m2m objects, I made a save object that wraps the old save_m2m method in a new method.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    group = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    if commit:
        group.user_set = self.cleaned_data['users']
    else:
        old_save_m2m = self.save_m2m
        def new_save_m2m():
            old_save_m2m()
            group.user_set = self.cleaned_data['users']
        self.save_m2m = new_save_m2m
    return group
```

Comment: I can confirm this is the correct way to handle M2M relations.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Django 2.1 and was using the solution posted by Chris, but like explained by Cedric, it wouldn't work when when a new group was added and simultaneously users were added to the new group. Unfortunately, his code didn't help either, but I could get it to work using this modified version below.

**Edit**: I included the suggestion of user *am70* (thanks!) and made use of `get_user_model()`. This code continues to work with Django 3.1 and has been tested with Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model ; User = get_user_model()
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), 
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name=_('Users'),
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Group

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.users.all()


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(GroupAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if 'users' in form.cleaned_data:
            form.instance.user_set.set(form.cleaned_data['users'])


admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

Comment: This one is the only one working AFAICT in django 3. Also I recommend not importing `User` but instead `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model ; User = get_user_model()`

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks. I included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler approach that uses Django's InlineModelAdmin objects ([answered here on Qubanshi.cc](http://Here%20is%20a%20simpler%20approach%20that%20uses%20Django's%20InlineModelAdmin%20objects))

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class UserSetInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = User.groups.through
    raw_id_fields = ('user',)  # optional, if you have too many users

class MyGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):
    inlines = [UserSetInline]

# unregister and register again
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, MyGroupAdmin)
```