# Django: how to add users to group in bulk in admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add many users to group based on filter and my selection in admin panel.
But the user change list view does not provide such action. 
So is there a way to do this? Any snippet or app?

No shell please because I hope people other than developers can do it.
I am surprised Django does not provide a way for such a common task.

Thanks!

[This can save some time but not flexible. I can't filter and really "bulk" add.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097210/assign-user-objects-to-a-group-while-editing-group-object-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this particular functionality is not yet exposed on the panel. You'll have to roll your sleeves and open up the shell. You can use the following snippet, just put your filters where .get() and .exclude() are defined.

```
 $ python manage.py shell
    >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
    >>> my_group = Group.objects.get(name='groupname')
    >>> my_users = User.objects.filter(<your_filter>)
    >>> for my_user in my_users:
    ...    my_group.user_set.add(my_user)
```

Comment: Just as I said I hope non-developers can do it. Anyway thank you!

Comment: This is where open-source really shines. YOU can put in this functionality on the django source-code, for everyone else, including you, to benefit from.

Comment: I am looking for existing snippet or app for this common task. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You can add an action to the UserAdmin that runs the above code snippet for the selection. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Answer (score 0):

### Create A new Form  Like This to add users to group in bulk

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

class GroupAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
    
    group_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label=u'Usuários deste Grupo', queryset=User.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        users_id = list()
        # Avoid 'No exception supplied' 
        try: 
            users = self.instance.group.user_set.all()
            for u in users:
                users_id.append(u.id)
            if self.fields.has_key('group_users'):
                self.fields['group_users'].initial = users_id
        except Exception, e:
            pass

    def clean(self):
        group = self.cleaned_data['group']
        group.save()
        if group.user_set.all():
            group.user_set.clear()
        try:
            users = self.cleaned_data['group_users']
            for user in users:
                group.user_set.add(user)
        except:
            return self.cleaned_data
        return self.cleaned_data
```