# 'Group' object has no attribute 'user_set'

Tags: python, django

Since the default django admin group form does not have field for selecting users in a group. I Wrote down some codes which i got online to add the selected users field.Everything is working just fine. Until i tried saving the group form i created, I get this error 'Group' object has no attribute 'user_set'

```
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=group
        exclude=[]
    users=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User,objects.all(),widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users',False),required=False)
   def __int__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(GroupAdminForm,self).__int__(*args,**kwargs)
       if self.instance.pk:
           self.fields['users'].initial=self.instance.user_set.all()
   def save_m2m(self):
       self.instance.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data['users'])
   def save(self,*args,*kwargs):
       instance= super(GroupAdminForm,self).save()
       self.save_m2m()
       return instance
```

I am getting this error 'Group' object has no attribute 'user_set' . I donot know on how to go about resolving this problem . Please help . I am navies in django.   Help Hlep please

Answer (score 0):

My personal error to this, after following answers such as [this one, covering how to add the ability to edit groups in the admin section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097210/assign-user-objects-to-a-group-while-editing-group-object-in-django-admin/41966816), was that I had an "add_form" in my CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin) that referred to the Group Admin form.

To expand, my original code looked like:

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = GroupAdmin # this right here was the culprit
    model = CustomUser
    ordering = ('date_published',)
    ...
```

I found that the `GroupAdmin` form, which is:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(GroupAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if 'users' in form.cleaned_data:
            form.instance.user_set.set(form.cleaned_data['users'])
```

should only be attached to the "Group" model, rather than the user model. As such, I continually got the error above.

Simply deleting the problem code and following "updated" answer from Ekad solved my problem.

For people who may be beginners like me, I was able to debug this through setting Breakpoints in Django where I found that the `self.instance` was a "{Group}". With that, why should I be adding a form related to groups to my extended user model?

This of course is basic to more experienced developers, but it was the hard to catch error that produced this bug for me.